# How to properly get SSIS package's ExecutionInstanceGUID before and after executing it from asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssis

I'm working with SQL Server 2008, SSIS 2008 for the package, and Visual Studio 2010 for C# asp.net app.

I'm trying to write a logfile of a package's execution process, from it's launch to end. This package is launched from an asp.net website where some parameters are asked to the user. Once executed, the package itself writes a message on the logfile.

While it's working in general, I'm trying to include in the logfile something that identifies the whole process, like ExecutionInstanceGUID.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    string fileName = "";
    string logFilePath = "";

    protected void Log(string guid,string message)
    {
        if (!this.logFilePath.Equals(""))
        {
            using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(this.logFilePath.ToString(), true))
            {
                _testData.WriteLine("[{0} {1}] {2}", guid, DateTime.Now.ToString(), message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: What to do if logfile path is not set?
        }
    }

    protected void File_Store()
    {
        this.fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
        fileName = Server.MapPath("App_Data//" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileName);        
    }

    protected void FileUpload1_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        this.File_Store();

        OleDbConnection oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + this.fileName.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");
        try
        {
            oleDbConn.Open();
            oleDbConn.Close();
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        Package package = null;
        String PackagePath = "";

        this.logFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/log.txt");

        if (Page.IsValid == true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Load DTSX
                PackagePath = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Packages\CargarFormulario\CargaFormulario.dtsx";
                package = app.LoadPackage(PackagePath, null);

                Log(package.Variables["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString(), "Package Loaded");

                //Global package variables
                Hashtable param = new Hashtable();
                param["ServidorOrigen"] = ServidorOrigen.Text.ToString();
                param["UserOrigen"] = UserOrigen.Text.ToString();
                param["PassOrigen"] = PassOrigen.Text.ToString();
                param["BaseDatosOrigen"] = BaseDatosOrigen.Text.ToString();
                param["EstadoConexion"] = 0;
                param["EstadoPaquete"] = 0;
                param["ExcelRuta"] = this.fileName.ToString();
                param["LogFile"] = this.logFilePath.ToString();

                Variables vars = null;

                //Assigns variables
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in param)
                {
                    package.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite(entry.Key.ToString(), ref vars);

                    try
                    {
                        vars[entry.Key.ToString()].Value = entry.Value;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw new Exception("variable " + entry.Key.ToString() + " not found in package");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        vars.Unlock();
                    }
                }

                Log(package.Variables["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString(), "Parameters assigned");

                Log(package.Variables["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString(), "Executing Package");
                //Execute DTSX
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();

                //Collects debugging info
                if (!package.Errors.Count.Equals(0))
                {
                    Log(package.Variables["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString(), "Execution aborted");
                    ErrorEnumerator myEnumerator = package.Errors.GetEnumerator();

                    while ((myEnumerator.MoveNext()) && (myEnumerator.Current != null))
                        Log(package.Variables["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString(), myEnumerator.Current.Description.ToString().TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()));                                            

                }
                Log(package.Variables["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString(), "------- END -------");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The web app code above produces the following logfile, given an execution with parameters ok and a second one with a bad password.

```
[{1863B2FA-16C7-4522-92FA-C89299D8950A} 10-02-2015 11:41:34] Package Loaded
[{1863B2FA-16C7-4522-92FA-C89299D8950A} 10-02-2015 11:41:34] Parameters assigned
[{1863B2FA-16C7-4522-92FA-C89299D8950A} 10-02-2015 11:41:34] Executing Package
[{1863B2FA-16C7-4522-92FA-C89299D8950A} 10-02-2015 11:41:34] El proceso de carga al Data Mart ha finalizado Correctamente.
[{70981D87-26AF-4D49-A8FD-686D0066E30C} 10-02-2015 11:41:35] ------- END -------
[{E426CD7A-AA21-4EE9-946B-AA0D664A79F8} 10-02-2015 11:42:41] Package Loaded
[{E426CD7A-AA21-4EE9-946B-AA0D664A79F8} 10-02-2015 11:42:41] Parameters assigned
[{E426CD7A-AA21-4EE9-946B-AA0D664A79F8} 10-02-2015 11:42:41] Executing Package
[{91C3EA18-42CD-445B-BA18-98A5D1659FA2} 10-02-2015 11:42:41] Execution aborted
[{91C3EA18-42CD-445B-BA18-98A5D1659FA2} 10-02-2015 11:42:41] Código de error SSIS DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. Error de OLE DB. Código de error: 0x80040E4D.
Hay un registro OLE DB disponible. Origen: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Resultado: 0x80040E4D Descripción: "Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'keber'.".
[{91C3EA18-42CD-445B-BA18-98A5D1659FA2} 10-02-2015 11:42:41] No se pudo adquirir la conexión "servidor". Puede ser que la conexión no esté configurada correctamente o que no tenga los permisos adecuados en esta conexión.
[{91C3EA18-42CD-445B-BA18-98A5D1659FA2} 10-02-2015 11:42:41] ------- END -------
```

While I expect different ExecutionInstanceGUID for different runs (@11:41 and @11:42), I noticed that I'm getting different ExecutionInstanceGUID before and after package execution. Indeed, the message "El proceso de carga...", which is wrote by the package itself and not by the web app code shown above, has the same GUID than the messages written by the web app.

While I think I can store the GUID in a variable to avoid this issue, I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: The ExecutionInstanceGUID you are passing to Log method, third line in the try in the button click event doesn't make sense. That's going to pass in the stored, design time value of `ExecutionInstanceGUID`. It's not until the package actually begins execution, `package.Execute` that an ID would be generated

Comment: I would agree, but in the log file I would expect the same GUID (stored, design time value) for each execution, but that's not the case. Also, the last message of a correct package execution ("El proceso de carga al Data Mart...") is written by the package itself (script task), which has the same GUID than the above messages which are written byt the web app, before executing the package.